# Spring MVC with multiple database connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hello I am building my first Spring MVC and Thymeleaf web app and I do not know how to connect to two different Oracle databases. I managed to connect to just one.

Here is the code:

Repository code:

```
    package com.example.demo;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author 40723
 */
@Repository
public class TelefonMailRepositoryImpl implements TelefonMailRepository {
    
    
 private final DataSource dataSourceMail;
 private final DataSource inregIvg;   
 
 public TelefonMailRepositoryImpl(DataSource dataSourceMail, @Qualifier("inregIvg") DataSource inregIvg) {
        this.dataSourceMail = dataSourceMail;
        this.inregIvg = inregIvg;

    }
    

 
 
  public Map<String, Object> findByNumber(String telefon) {
      
        Map<String, Object> toateTel;
      
        String query = "select cnp, nume, prenume from utilizatori where telefon=?";
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSourceMail);
        jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query,telefon);
        Map<String, Object> info1 = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query,telefon);
       // return info1;
      
       String query2 = "select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?";
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2 = new JdbcTemplate(this.inregIvg);
       Map<String, Object> info2 = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query2,telefon);
       
      if(info2.isEmpty()) {
          return info1;
      } else {
          return info2;
      }
       
    
       }
    
    
    public Map<String, Object> findByEmail(String email) {
        
        
        
        String query = "select cnp, nume, prenume from utilizatori where upper(email)=upper(?)";
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSourceMail);
        Map<String, Object> info1 = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query, email);
        
        String query2 = "select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where upper(email)=upper(?)";
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2 = new JdbcTemplate(this.inregIvg);
        Map<String, Object> info2 = jdbcTemplate2.queryForMap(query2,email);
        
        if(info2.isEmpty()) {
            return info1;
        } else {
            return info1;
        }


    }
    
    
    public DataSource getDataSourceMail() {
        return dataSourceMail;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

This is the DbConfig file:

```
    package com.example.demo;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

/**
 *
 * @author 40723
 */
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

   @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.dsmail")
    public DataSourceProperties dsmailDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="DSMail")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.dsmail.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceMail() {
        return dsmailDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.inregivg")
    public DataSourceProperties inregIvgDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "inregIvg")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.inregivg.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceInregIvg() {
        return inregIvgDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
    

}
```

And here are the application properties:

```
app.datasource.dsmail.username=xxx
app.datasource.dsmail.password=xxx
app.datasource.dsmail.url=dburl:123
app.datasource.dsmail.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
app.datasource.dsmail.configuration.pool-name=DSMailPool
app.datasource.dsmail.configuration.auto-commit=false

app.datasource.inregivg.username=yyy
app.datasource.inregivg.password=yyy
app.datasource.inregivg.url=dburl2:321
app.datasource.inregivg.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
app.datasource.inregivg.configuration.pool-name=DSInregivgPool
app.datasource.inregivg.configuration.auto-commit=false
```

I have changed the user, pass, and url of application props because of security reasons.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

The error that I get is:

```
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Mar 21 12:00:20 EET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:879)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForMap(JdbcTemplate.java:916)
    at com.example.demo.TelefonMailRepositoryImpl.findByNumber(TelefonMailRepositoryImpl.java:56)
    at com.example.demo.TelefonMailRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ecef6002.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.example.demo.TelefonMailRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$637cc014.findByNumber(<generated>)
    at com.example.demo.TelefonMailService.getRaspuns(TelefonMailService.java:25)
    at com.example.demo.TelefonMailController.postDbRequest(TelefonMailController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:630)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:564)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1151)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:771)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:937)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1172)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1101)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3746)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3855)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1098)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 28, Sql = select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=:1 , OriginalSql = select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:637)
    ... 89 more
```

Just as a reminder with one connection it works it retrieves the desired info but with two datasources it does not work. I made the select that spits the error in Toad and it works so the tabvle exists. Thanks in advance. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

The connection is successful but it can't be find a table in db. I think you need to separate package of models by each db and the configuration class should be know the package name for each db. For example for JPA:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.project.modelpackage"
)
public class ClassName { ... }
```